# Error with Capture URL / Catch URL in HTTrack

Tags: proxy, httrack

I have a problem when click capture URL from HTTrack.
That is it generate a Proxy address not correct.

This is result :

Please TEMPORARILY set your browser's proxy preferences to:

Proxy's address:  fe80::141b:2ce3:3f57:fefb

Proxy's port:    8080

I disable IPV6. but it still such that.
Can you see detail from http://clip2net.com/s/iyDXY7

Answer (score 3):

No need to disable IPv6.

Quoting the address with "[]" will do the trick.

```
address: [fe80::141b:2ce3:3f57:fefb]
port: 8080
```

**Resources**

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cc2020f7-9680-4494-bae6-e47e3770b977/cannot-enter-ipv6-address-in-ies-proxy-settings-but-dns-name-works?forum=w7itpronetworking

Answer (score 2):

The following [solution](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/23698/16681/index.html) worked for me.

The problem comes from the fact that Windows 7 (maybe Vista and Windows 8, I haven't tested) forces HTTracks to generates IPv6 addresses for the proxy.

If you want to disable IPv6 on your machine, create a new registry key in:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters`
with the value `"DisabledComponents"=dword:000000ff`

For more information about how to set up HTTracks to catch URL with a proxy, go [here](http://httrack.kauler.com/help/CatchURL_tutorial).